# Dynamic Array updates after sort even when i store it?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hey guys im quite confused at the moment in regards to sorting a dynamic array. The assignement im doing is telling me I have to test each sorting algorithm given 4 sorting algortihms in a jar file. (they are not identified, which is the major question for the assignment. i.e which sorting algorithm is which and how did you find out)

The way im approaching the question is to test a randomly generated dynamic array with 'n' integers inside each integer being randomly chosen from 0 -100. This is all fine for the first sorting algorithm however the dynamic array updates itself once i have sorted it once with sorting algorthim A and therefore i cannot use the same array because its already sorted. 
Ive tried assigning the dynamic array to a temporary array and then reassigning the original array to the temporary one but its not working.

Anyways below is the code i have written, my question is how can i store the random values in the orginal array and access them at any given time to be sorted by one of the four algorithms.

notice that i have used a stopwatch to essentially time the sorting process for each sort thus being able to compare the algorithms and identify which sort they all are.

```
public static Vector<Integer> dataStore(Vector<Integer> n){
    Vector<Integer> store = new Vector<Integer>();
    store = n;
    return store;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int n= 10;
    Vector<Integer> x= generateData(n);

    Vector<Integer> temp = dataStore(x);
    System.out.println("aaaa" + dataStore(x));
    StopWatch s= new StopWatch(); //iniate stopwatch

    //SORT A
    System.out.println("SORT A");
    s.start(); // This is how to call the stopwatch
    SortingAlgorithms.sortingA(x);// Given a list x (which you should make yourself),                                       
    s.stop();   // This is how to stop the stopwatch.
    s.getElapsedTimeSecs(); // This returns the difference      
    printTime(s);
    System.out.println(">>>" + dataStore(x));
    s.reset();

    //SORT B

    System.out.println("SORT B");
   s.start();
   SortingAlgorithms.sortingB(temp);
   s.stop();
   s.getElapsedTimeSecs();
   printTime(s);
   System.out.println(x);
   s.reset();

   //SORT C
    System.out.println("SORT C");
   s.start();
   SortingAlgorithms.sortingC(x);
   s.stop();
   s.getElapsedTime();
   printTime(s);
   System.out.println(x);
   x = temp;
   s.reset();

   //SORT D
   System.out.println("SORT D");
   s.start();
   SortingAlgorithms.sortingD(x);
   s.stop();
   s.getElapsedTime();
   printTime(s);
   System.out.println(x);
   x = temp;
   s.reset();
}
```

}
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Code `Vector<Integer> store = new Vector<Integer>(); store = n;` is exactly equal to just `Vector<Integer> store = n;`, the new vector is lost (garbage collected). Try actully copying...

Comment: `store = n;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You are just referencing the vector reference `store` to vector instance `n`.
Try using `clone()` method as

```
store = (Vector) n.clone();
```

This will create a new copy of your vector.

Comment: You don't need to use `clone` - `Vector` has a copy constructor [Vector(Collection<? extends E> c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: okay so vector has its own copy constructor so i should just use that ?